# sed print text between two specific characters

Tags: search, sed, character

I have some lines of a playlist file and want to extract the filename only and get printed out for every line:

```
<location>file:///mnt/c3/jtvtes/ww/adw.avi</location>
<location>file:///mnt/c2/clown.mp4</location>
<location>file:///mnt/c2/jtv/video/ww/god.mp3</location>
```

From those lines I only need:

```
adw.avi
clown.mp4
god.mp3
```

So I tried to extract the text between the "/" and the "<" characters with:

```
sed -r 's/^(.*)pat1(.*)pat2(.*)$/\2/g'
```

modified to:

```
sed -r 's/^(.*)/(.*)<(.*)$/\2/g'
```

but this doesn't work, does someone have an idea/solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
sed -r 's|.*/(.*)</.*|\1|' file
```

Answer (score 2):

when I want to **extract** stuff, `grep` comes up first.

try this line:

```
grep -Po "(?<=/)[^/]*(?=<)" file
```

Answer (score 0):

When it's XML, do that bit first, to avoid error:

```
lxprintf -e location "%s\n" . yourfilename | awk -F '{print $NF}'
```

That guarantees you get the text content, line by line. lxprintf is part of the LTxml2 toolkit from http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/software/ltxml2. The awk then gives you the last slash-delimited token.

If you need to embed this in a production workflow where the regular utilities are less easily acessible or acceptable, use XSLT2:

```
<xsl:template match="location">
  <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(.,'/')[position()=last()]"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```